# How to convert varbinary to file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, filestream

I'm trying to convert a varbinary to file (any file), I saved the file in the database with this code:

```
    byte[] bytes;
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fuFile.PostedFile.FileName);
    string contentType = fuFile.PostedFile.ContentType;
    using (Stream fs = fuFile.PostedFile.InputStream)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
        }
    }
```

It saved a code like: `0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010200.....` and I need to convert that to a file again. I use this to get the file but it shows an error `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` in `C://`

```
    byte[] buffer = (byte[])FileinDB;
    File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\", buffer);
```

what is the best way to get and download that file?

Comment: It looks like 'file name' you are trying to `WriteAllBytes` to is not a valid filename, but rather the root folder of the C: drive.

Comment: You need to include the file name,  not just the directory.  The way you are saving to the database does not include the file name (or the type/extension) in the binary data.  You need to save the file name too. Also don't assume you have permissions to write to the root directory.

Comment: That was a silly error of my part, I did not know that, I'm really new with c#, but thanks for correcting me.